How to end an event inside another function in python?
def start():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SLASH:
                    print("Ok")
                    break


ustvari_mrežo()
while nezapri:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            nezapri = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            nariši_zelen_kvadrat(event)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                start()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()

As you can see I have a problem because I want to end some code in function with / and then go back to main code. I want to start that function wtih space from main code, and then after function end go back to main code. Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried many stupid things. As a result I want to do something in function when i press space and then end function with / and continue main code.
